# Deploy Multiple Containers AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

In full disclosure, I am trying to dive into AWS, and I have a POC app that I want to deploy as part of my learning, but I am getting stuck.  I have been going through the AWS docs, attempting to read various tutorials, but it's not apparent how to proceed.

What I am looking to deploy:

- Two separate streamlit apps.  Each would be their own Docker Container and ideally I don't have to worry about the port. Simply, it would be great if each could be built using port 8501.
- I want to bundle those apps in a way that I would access them via URL/app1 and URL/app2, or something along those lines.

As I noted above, I am looking to wrap my head around the various parts to get this deployed.

From what I have gathered:

- Each instance would be its own entry in ECR.  Pushing the image from local to ECR is straightforward and something that I have done.

This is the stage where things start to get hazy for me.  I understand that ECS is involved and that tasks seemingly point to the entries in ECR, but I am lost as to how to proceed. After fumbling around in ECS, I am stopping.  I kinda figured I would get these configured as tasks in ECS and then point API gateway to orchestrate the apps as described above, but no luck.

Finally, I am just looking to deploy this as a POC, and will tear it down once I can get this setup, so security/user access is not urgent at this stage.

My question:  How can I deploy two streamlit apps to the web such that they are orchestrated via url/app1 and url/app2?

Comment: It sounds like you need to create two ECS task definitions, and then two ECS Services that use those task definitions. You will also need a load balancer. Your question is so vague and lacking any details about what you have tried, and where you are stuck, that it's impossible to really provide a full answer to your question.

Comment: Vague yes, but I have attempted so many variations that I am trying to elevate my question to a higher level.  Ultimately I have no idea where to even start.  To your comment, I wasnt expecting to do two separate tasks, two separate ECS services.  Even higher level I expected I could store each image in a single ECR, but that also doesn't seem to be the way to go.  My point is that at each step, things haven't behaved the way I expected.  AWS does a great job at providing all sorts of docs but the info tends to imply that you are well-versed across the entire AWS ecosystem, which I am not.

Comment: Your last comment is more of a rant against AWS than a clarification of your question. Again, I would be happy to help you, but first you need to post a **specific** question. If you want to deploy them both in a single ECS task definition and single ECS service that is certainly possible. You have to provide those **specific** details in your question, and provide **specific** details about what errors or unexpected behaviors you are encountering before anyone can really provide you a concrete answer.

Comment: My question.  How can I use AWS to deploy an "app" that is comprised of two separate instances A & B where the running container for instance A is found at URL/app1 and the container for instance B is found at URL/app2?  In this solution, I want to avoid having a server running 247/365. I don't have any other design requirements.  I attempted to solve this myself and while services/tasks appear to have built properly I never was presented with a URL to even preview app A or B. Any guidance appreciated as I really am lost on how to get started.

Comment: You have this question tagged with Fargate/ECS, but that is a service that runs 24/7/365. If you don't want something running 24/7/365 your only option on AWS is to rearchitect your entire application to run on AWS Lambda. If you want to continue down the ECS/Fargate path then you need to configure an ECS task definition with two containers, and deploy that as an ECS Service that is connected to an Application Load Balancer. You would add rules in the load balancer to point /app1 to one container, and /app2 to another container.

Comment: ECS doesn't "present you with a URL to preview your app". It just runs some containers. You need to connect a load balancer to get a public URL for your apps.

Comment: Thank you!  I was under the impression that fargate spun up and down based on usage.  Simply, I want to avoid running an EC2 instance that will be idle most of the time.  This is very helpful.  You mentioned lambda above.  I never even thought a lambda could be used in this case, interesting.

Comment: Fargate runs 24/7. It doesn't spin/up down. Fargate simply allows you to run containers without managing the underlying server yourself. You could look at AWS AppRunner which is kind of like ECS/Fargate, but it does suspend your container when it's not in use in order to save you some money. It still charges some for the suspended container, but much less than when the container is running.